# Cannot remove duplicate values from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table ship_details which is not having any constraints. The data is coming from a data source & original designer of the table thought the incoming data not to have duplication.Now I have to remove the duplicate entries. Now the table has 9,94,184 entries.
The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE `ship_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_number` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick_date` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pn_note_number` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_code` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picked_quantity` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot_number` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot_expiry` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivered_date` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib3` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib4` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib5` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib6` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib7` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib8` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib9` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_attrib10` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outbound_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=994222 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried to delete the duplicate entries by using following script:

```
delete s1 
from ship_details s1 
inner join ship_details s2 
where  s1.id < s2.id 
and s2.order_number = s1.order_number
and s2.delivery_id = s1.delivery_id 
and s2.item_code = s1.item_code 
and s2.lot_number = s1.lot_number 
and s2.picked_quantity = s1.picked_quantity;
```

but that gave lock wait timeout. Even if I use a particular order no still it times out.
So I went for the approach of replicating the table with unique constraint of order_number, delivery_id, item_code and picked_quantity.
So tried to export the data from the original table after running following command:

```
SELECT distinct order_number, delivery_id, transaction_type, pick_date, pn_note_number, 
item_id, item_code, picked_quantity, lot_number, lot_expiry, name, delivered_date, 
extra_attrib10,last_updated, outbound_id
FROM ship_details;
```

But this command did not give me unique result. This results in 1,54,948 rows. Pl. see this:

```
INSERT INTO clean_ship_details (order_number,delivery_id,transaction_type,pick_date,pn_note_number,item_id,item_code,picked_quantity,lot_number,lot_expiry,name,delivered_date,extra_attrib10,last_updated,outbound_id) VALUES
     ('181020373','10068965','Shipped','2018-11-11T15:50:48.000+04:00','PN176348','516169','VCH128','73','C34142','2021-02-28T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6410','2019-06-18T15:48:12.000+04:00','','2019-06-18T15:54:40.000+04:00','51616973_73_'),
     ('181020373','10068965','Shipped','2018-11-11T15:50:48.000+04:00','PN176348','516169','VCH128','73','C34142','2021-02-28T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6410','2019-06-18T15:48:12.000+04:00','','2019-06-18T15:54:40.000+04:00','58719373_73_'),
     ('181020373','10068965','Shipped','2018-11-11T15:50:48.000+04:00','PN176348','516170','VCH120','12','K33471/A','2020-10-31T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6410','2019-06-18T15:48:12.000+04:00','','2019-06-18T15:54:40.000+04:00','51617012_12_'),
     ('181020373','10068965','Shipped','2019-06-19T12:22:39.000+04:00','PN239867','587193','VCH128','2','E34284','2021-04-30T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6410','2019-06-18T15:48:12.000+04:00','','2019-06-18T15:54:40.000+04:00','5161692_2_'),
     ('181020373','10068965','Shipped','2019-06-19T12:22:39.000+04:00','PN239867','587193','VCH128','2','E34284','2021-04-30T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6410','2019-06-18T15:48:12.000+04:00','','2019-06-18T15:54:40.000+04:00','5871932_2_'),
     ('191002479','10091039','Shipped','2019-02-12T07:50:55.000+04:00','PN186154','544495','VTP048','170','205809','2020-07-31T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6479','2019-07-11T07:30:38.000+04:00','','2019-07-11T09:31:22.000+04:00','544495170_170_'),
     ('191002479','10091039','Shipped','2019-02-12T07:50:55.000+04:00','PN186154','544495','VTP048','170','205809','2020-07-31T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6479','2019-07-11T07:30:38.000+04:00','','2019-07-11T09:31:22.000+04:00','594447170_170_'),
     ('191002479','10091039','Shipped','2019-07-18T07:45:49.000+04:00','PN249274','594447','VTP048','11','208744','2021-01-31T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6479','2019-07-11T07:30:38.000+04:00','','2019-07-11T09:31:22.000+04:00','54449511_11_'),
     ('191002479','10091039','Shipped','2019-07-18T07:45:49.000+04:00','PN249274','594447','VTP048','11','208744','2021-01-31T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6479','2019-07-11T07:30:38.000+04:00','','2019-07-11T09:31:22.000+04:00','59444711_11_'),
     ('191006312','10188037','Shipped','2019-03-31T12:17:39.000+04:00','PN201490','560373','VTP048','26','207783','2020-12-31T00:00:00.000+04:00','DVT-6694','2019-10-08T07:08:45.000+04:00','','2019-10-08T07:11:44.000+04:00','56037326_26_');
```

I cannot insert this to the new table.
**Update** I tried to insert using a script without success as I get lock wait time exceeded even with a limit of just 1 record:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO clean_ship_details (order_number,delivery_id,transaction_type,pick_date,pn_note_number,item_id,item_code,picked_quantity,lot_number,lot_expiry,name,delivered_date,last_updated,outbound_id) SELECT order_number,delivery_id,transaction_type,pick_date,pn_note_number,item_id,item_code,picked_quantity,lot_number,lot_expiry,name,delivered_date,last_updated,outbound_id FROM ship_details order by order_number,delivery_id,item_id limit 10;
```

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining only the data you want to keep, then delete the old table, then rename (and re-index) the new table.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is a set modifier; it applies across all selected columns.

Comment: It's hard to see what makes a duplicate - your first query has far fewer columns in the where column  than your second query has in the select. Also your first query does not have an ON in the join.which may be causing the timeout..

Comment: @Strawberry, I understand that but you see first 2 rows all columns are same. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Subhendu Mahanta what's the significance of your last comment?

Comment: @P Salmon, ohh.. missed the on clause for the inner join. Will correct that.

Comment: Tried to use on clause in the inner join condition of the delete script, it is telling not valid sql syntax. As distinct is not  working fully, should I reduce columns in the unique constraint definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach does dedupe if as you say  unique constraint of order_number, delivery_id, item_code and picked_quantity also you don't need distinct because unique key will detect the duplicates and you can INSERT IGNORE the error

Using your sample data

[enter link description here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oKreqXnhH6zErNKg1nZDkB/0)

Comment: I have exported current data of ship_details to a sql script & running the script manually which inserts data in a chunk of 10 at a time. But that is too much work.If I try to insert using script I get lock wait time exceeded.